# How to display an array of pair arrays as key values pairs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am writing a client in Ract that receives streaming data representing objects from a back end. The client parses this data and dynamically builds the object as a javascript data structure (typically an object or an array).
The backend has a `Timeseries` datatype that consists of timestamp keys and arbitrary values. A `Timeseries` can have duplicate timestamp keys like so:

```
{
 '2019-08-22T18:34:15.777927965Z' : 1,
 '2019-08-22T18:34:15.777927965Z' : 2,
 '2019-08-22T18:34:15.777927965Z' : 3,
}
```

This means that I cannot use a javascript object to build this datastructure in the client given that only the last key/value pair added will be stored since the keys are the same.

My solution was to collect this data in an array:

```
[
    ['2019-08-22T18:34:15.777927965Z', 1],
    ['2019-08-22T18:34:15.777927965Z', 2],
    ['2019-08-22T18:34:15.777927965Z', 3],
]
```

The problem is that I have been asked to display this data in key/value format the way a javascript object would be displayed.
I am using the [`react-json-tree`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-json-tree) npm package to dislpay all the objects I am constructing which just takes an object or array and formats it nicely with collapsable dropdown arrows in the UI (this is not essential).
What options do I have to turn my array of arrays in the code into a nicely formatted object like data structure in the UI?

**TLDR:**
How do I display an array like this:

```
[
    ['2019-08-22T18:34:15.777927965Z', 1],
    ['2019-08-22T18:34:15.777927965Z', 2],
    ['2019-08-22T18:34:15.777927965Z', 3],
]
```

As colon separated key/value pairs in the UI, like objects?
Ideally I could pass this data structure into a library like [`react-json-tree`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-json-tree).

Comment: the solution you said you had and the solution you were asked to provide are the same ? Which is the result you are looking for ?

Comment: Maybe I'm being daft, but wouldn't something like `'2019-08-22T18:34:15.777927965Z': [1, 2, 3]` work fine?

Comment: @MihaiT The solution I had was to the problem of how to represent this data structure. What I am looking for is a way to display it in the UI as a list of key/value colon separated pair (the same way objects are).

Comment: @coltonb We want the result in the UI to resemble the original datatype as closely as possible and so changing the structure of the data isn't an option.

Comment: There must be some additional information attached to each timestamp value pair that you can use then, right?

Comment: @coltonb unfortunately not. This is a very specific but needed use-case.

Comment: better data structures can be 
`{ '2019-08-22T18:34:15.777927965Z' : [1, 2, 3]}` 
OR even better
`[{key:'2019-08-22T18:34:15.777927965Z', value: 1 }, {key:'2019-08-22T18:34:15.777927965Z', value: 2 }, {key:'2019-08-22T18:34:15.777927965Z', value: 3 } ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display your data in the following way, if you want them to be given as a list :

```js
const data = [
    ['2019-08-22T18:34:15.777927965Z', 1],
    ['2019-08-22T18:34:15.777927965Z', 2],
    ['2019-08-22T18:34:15.777927965Z', 3],
]
 
 const Renderer = () =>
  <ul>
    {data.map(([key, val], id) => <li key={id}>{key}; {val}</li>)}
  </ul>;
 
ReactDOM.render(<Renderer/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

To display it using `react-json-tree`, how about wrapping your array within an object ?

```
const data = [
    ['2019-08-22T18:34:15.777927965Z', 1],
    ['2019-08-22T18:34:15.777927965Z', 2],
    ['2019-08-22T18:34:15.777927965Z', 3],
]

<JSONTree data={{log: data}} />
```

OR

```
const data = {
  log : [
    ['2019-08-22T18:34:15.777927965Z', 1],
    ['2019-08-22T18:34:15.777927965Z', 2],
    ['2019-08-22T18:34:15.777927965Z', 3],
  ]
}

<JSONTree data={log} />
```

Comment: Ideally I would have liked to have been able to use the `react-json-tree` library for displaying my data but this looks like the next best solution. (I will just have to substitute the comma for a colon).

Comment: I took a quick look at the `react-json-tree` library, would the above solution work ? I also replaced the first one with  a semicolon

Comment: Well, the library actually allows you to display arrays directly however my original goal was to actually have the keys be the timestamps (as opposed to "log") so that the data would look like a JS object with duplicate keys, sort of like what you have in your code snippet. The problem is that the library doesn't let me map the `<li>` elements like you have done.